# C# ASP.Net Core facing issues when integrating with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a controller DailyExpenseController and I am injecting the IQueryExecutor class into the controller.

DailyExpenseController

```
using HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.CrossCutting;
using HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.DTO;
using HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.Models;
using HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/DailyExpense/{Id}")]
    public class DailyExpenseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IQueryExecutor queryExecutor;

        public DailyExpenseController(IQueryExecutor queryExecutor)
        {
            this.queryExecutor = queryExecutor;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Create")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateExpense(long Id, [FromBody] Expenditure expenditure)
        {
            var findEntity = new FindEntityQuery<Expense>(Id);
            var find = queryExecutor.Execute(findEntity);

            /*if (find == null)
                return NotFound();*/


            var createExpenses = new CreateExpenditure(expenditure);
            var expenses = queryExecutor.Execute(createExpenses);
            return Ok(expenses);
        }

        /*If I write this method, it will result in 500 Error, because this method has id which is confusing 
         with the variable Id declared with Controller*/
        /*[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }*/

        [HttpGet("{id2}")]
        public string Get(long id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Below is my Autofac Configuration details

Startup.cs

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace HomeBudgetTrackingSystem
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        //public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            /*services.AddDbContext<BudgetContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BudgetConnection")
        )); */

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Populate(services);
            builder.RegisterModule(new RepositoryHandlerModule());
            //builder.RegisterType<QueryExecutor>().As<IQueryExecutor>();
            ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
        }

        public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
            appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Model Builder class where I have registered the dependencies

RepositoryHandlerModule.cs

```
using Autofac;
using HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.CrossCutting;

namespace HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.Repository
{
    public class RepositoryHandlerModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<QueryExecutor>().As<IQueryExecutor>().InstancePerRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

I have not made any changes to the Program.cs

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace HomeBudgetTrackingSystem
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Below are the exception details I received

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: Unable to resolve the type 'HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.CrossCutting.QueryExecutor' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
>   - HomeBudgetTrackingSystem.CrossCutting.IQueryExecutor
>
> Details ---> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.
>
> If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself. (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.
>
> If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself.
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime.FindScope(ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup..ctor(IComponentRegistration registration, IResolveOperation context, ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup..ctor(IComponentRegistration registration, IResolveOperation context, ISharingLifetimeScope mostNestedVisibleScope, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

I have referred multiple links on these. The prominent ones are

http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html
http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html
(I preferred Configuration without Container)
http://www.codedigest.com/posts/49/using-autofac-instead-of-inbuilt-di-container-with-in-aspnet-core-mvc (This is the one I referred)

Could anyone please help me on these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to the problem.

http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

Here Under the Title 'Differences From ASP.NET Classic', lists a key point
Use InstancePerLifetimeScope instead of InstancePerRequest.

I also made a change in my RepositoryHandlerModule.cs like adding the BudgetContext.cs
which is as below

```
public class RepositoryHandlerModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);
            builder.RegisterType<QueryExecutor>().As<IQueryExecutor>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<BudgetContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
```